# Converting and Compressing a Video with FFmpeg

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using FFmpeg to convert and compress a video. Everything converts/compresses fine, but my video has no sound when I try to play it on a mobile device. But it has sound when I play it on a desktop. I don't know if this has to do with the codec that I am using, I don't know. Can someone help me? I appreciate it. Thank you.

The format that I am using in FFmpeg:

```
$request->video->move(public_path('/app'), $filename);
        $name_file=uniqid().'intro_video.mp4';
     $ffp=FFMpeg::open($filename)
->addFilter(function ($filters) {
    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));
})
->export()
->toDisk('s3')
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Aac)
->save($name_file);
```

Comment: I think it might be format issue. Usually when I was using html video tag I had to use three versions of the same video in different encoding for supporting all the browsers.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze thank you for replying. What was your solution? Do you mind sharing with me?

Comment: Well, I was not using laravel for video conversion. I did offline conversion into three different formats. In your case, you need to convert your videos into three different formats and then embed three files into the front end.  You will need mp4, ogg and webm formats I think. You can google cross browser html5 video tag.

Comment: You'll want AAC encoder, not MP3.

Comment: @Gyan how would I set it up. Also I am not using mp3. I'll edit my question and show you what I did

Comment: @Gyan take a look at my code. Do you mean that way?

Comment: No idea how ffmpeg-php api works.

Comment: @Gyan you don't know laravel ffmpeg? that's what I am using

Answer (score 0):

For FFmpeg version 4.0 you need to change the code from

```
inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Aac)
```

to

```
inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264'))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Audio compress
    $inputAudio = public_path('/audio/myaudio.mp3');
    $outputAudio = public_path('/output/outputAudio.mp3');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputAudio -ab 64 $outputAudio");

    // Video compress
    $inputVideo = public_path('/video/myvideo.mp4');
    $outputVideo = public_path('/output/outputVideo.mp4');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputVideo -vf scale=1280:-1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 24 $outputVideo");
```

For reference
https://ostechnix.com/20-ffmpeg-commands-beginners/

also run this command

> sudo apt install ffmpeg